# lucene: reopen indexreader after index

Tags: lucene

when my search server start to run, it will load all of the index at once for all queries. However, it's still use the old index even if I rebuild the index. So I think the I should tell the indexReader of searcher to reopen index after the server rebuild the index, but how to implement it?
Maybe use producer-consumer pattern? Although I can use indexReader.isCurrent() to check whether the index have changed, but I have to check this ever times to search or at some period. Is there any more efficient and real-time way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A convenient way to do what you are describing is to use Lucene's helper class [SearcherManager](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html). If you are interested in doing near-realtime search, you might also be interested in [NRTManager](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/NRTManager.html).

There is a very nice blog article about these two classes on [Mike McCandless' blog](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a simple task. I had to write quite a lot of code to achieve it (unfortunately, it's in Clojure, so no Java code samples at hand). The basic principle is to have a thread-safe reference to your IndexSearcher that is accessible to both the index reading code and index building code. The index builder starts creating a new index in the background; this does not interfere with the existing indexs. When done, it enters a synchronized block, closes the IndexReader and IndexSearcher, opens a new IndexReader, and updates the global IndexSearcher reference to the IndexSearcher created from it. All reading code must synchronize on the same lock as the one involved in the mentioned synchronized block. A better alternative is to use ReentrantReadWriteLock instead of a synchronized block. This will avoid unnecessary contention between many reader threads.

After initialization, during normal operation, you can use the NRTManager to simultaneously read the index and make incremental updates to it.